# WPF: Alternatives to Grid for displaying data?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, grid

What are the alternatives to Grid for displaying repeating data in WPF?

For example, how would I show customers as a list of business cards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a ListView and use a customized DataTemplate that shows each customer in some *business-card* like format. Here's a nice tutorial that does something similar: [WPF Twitter Tutorial](http://blog.richstern.com/?p=399).